# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')

Tags: javascript

I'm currently trying to parse anonymous functions and am currently getting the error as per the title. I've tested a few things, and the core math works, but there's an issue with parsing the information. Any help is appreciated.

In this instance, manaCost = 10 and manaLevel = 0

```
if(manaLevel>=1){
manaCost = increase(5,manaCost,1.17,manaLevel);
} else {
manaCost = increase(5,manaCost,1.17,1);
}
```

```
function increase(n,b,r,k){
    b * (Math.pow(r,k)*((Math.pow(r,n)-1)/(r-1)));
}
```

The core math of

```
manaCost * (Math.pow(1.17,1)*((Math.pow(1.17,5)-1)/(1.17-1)))
```

functions.

Comment: `increase` doesn’t return anything.

Comment: Your increase function is returning nothing

Comment: Thank you! That was a pleasantly easy fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a value in your functions if you want to assign something to the return value of the function. Otherwise it returns undefined.

```
function increase(n,b,r,k){
    return b * (Math.pow(r,k)*((Math.pow(r,n)-1)/(r-1)));
}
```